# specifying a unicode string for use with PyErr_SetString

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I have an error message that was built using PyUnicode_FromString.  I need to pass this message to PyErr_SetString.  Is there an equivalence to PyBytes_AsString for unicode to convert it back to an Ascii character string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an object for the message, use [`PyErr_SetObject()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_SetObject) instead.